# DocuSign send notification to listener web application on envelop completion

Tags: docusignapi

I gone through link https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-admin-guide-connect. As per document send trigger event and post inbound XML data to our web application. I have created MVC application and expose method and configure in connect. So my question is.. How get this xml data?
Do I get xml from HttpContext.Request.Form[0]?
Or there some other object I will get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some sample C# code, yes, you use the HttpContext.Request object

```
        using (Stream stream = Request.InputStream)
        {
            int streamLen = Convert.ToInt32(Request.InputStream.Length);
            byte[] streamArray = new byte[streamLen];
            // Read stream into byte array.
            int streamRead = stream.Read(streamArr, 0, streamLen);
            requestContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(streamArrary);
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(EnvelopeInformation));
            stream.Position = 0;
            var xmlTextReader = new TextReader(stream);
            envelopeInformation = (EnvelopeInformation)serializer.Deserialize(xmlTextReader);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Inbar. Below is working for me

```
using (Stream stream = Request.InputStream)
{
int streamLen = Convert.ToInt32(Request.InputStream.Length);
byte[] streamArray = new byte[streamLen];
// Read stream into byte array.
int streamRead = stream.Read(streamArray, 0, streamLen);
string requestContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(streamArray);              

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(ConfigurationHelper.FileSystem + 
@"\ErrorLog\docusignLog_" + 
System.DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmss") + ".txt", 
requestContents);
}
```